# SQL: At least one value exists in another table

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a table that has columns called `user_id` and `top5_foods` (binary column). I currently have two tables, one has all of the `user_id`s and the foods associated with those `user_id`s and one table that only contains the top5 foods according to a type of calculation to select the top5 foods.

The table that I am trying to create if to have the column of the `user_id` and if at least one of their favorite foods is in the `top_5_food` table, put the value of the `top5_foods` as 1 and if not, 0.

Something like the following:

```
user_id     top5_foods
----------------------
34223          1
43225          0
34323          1
```

I have tried to use the `CASE` command but it just duplicated the `user_id`s and mark 1 or 0 whenever it finds a food that is in the top_5_foods table. But I don't want it to duplicate. Could you please help ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, a `left join` and aggregation:

```
select uf.user_id,
       (count(t.food_id) > 0) as top5_foods
from user_foods uf left join
     top5_foods t
     on uf.food_id = t.food_id
group by uf.user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks it helps. But maybe I should have been more clear. The user_foods table has 2 columns called user_id and foods (This table might have duplicated rows as one user might like more than one type of food). The top_5_foods table only has one column called foods and only has one rows. I am trying to create a table in says if a user_id like one of the top_5_foods, mark it as one, or 0 if the foods they like is not in the top5 foods. @gordonlinoff

Comment: @Eli . . . Just remove the `user_id` condition in the `on` clause (which I did).

Comment: Great,  it actually makes sense and I tried it. But for some reasons, it returns all the values as True but I am pretty sure that they are some users who don't like have the top 5 foods associated with their account.

Comment: @Eli . . . You can add `array_agg(t.food_id ignore nulls)` to see what the matching foods are.

Comment: Thank you again! I checked and actually for some of the users, it shows an empty value as their food but still mark the value as true.

Comment: @Eli . . . Are you use you are referencing `top5_foods` in the `count()`?

Comment: @Eli . . . I originally had the wrong column, so the confusion is very understandable.  I didn't fix the `count()` when I fixed the `on` clause.